# How can I create a deferred transaction?

Tags: deferred-transactions

Are there any examples online for where I can see some examples of deferred transactions being created?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's super simple, from your contract just call the below code:

```
        transaction out{};
        out.actions.emplace_back(permission_level{_self, N(active)}, N(pet), N(feedpet), std::make_tuple(pet.id));
        out.delay_sec = 10;
        out.send(pet.id, _self);
```

It's basically wrap an action on a transaction object (so you must import `eoslib/transaction.hpp` on your header) and you set the quantity of seconds to defer the transaction, in the above case it's 10 seconds.

Comment: is that possible to stop deferred transaction which having been pushed in a contract ?

Comment: what means first parameter of transaction.send?

Comment: yes it's possible to stop a deferred transaction, check `cleos system` ... the first parameter of `transaction.send` is the id of the transaction you want to create

Comment: are deferred transactions visible the second they are sent? I want to use them to hide some information but reveal at a later time.

Comment: who will pay for CPU in case of a deferred or inline action, the contract or the initial caller?

Comment: @kasperTaeymans in case of a deferred action the contract pays for the CPU / NET bandwidth costs. There is no guarantee that a deferred action will be executed. It will also have the permission of the contract and not the initial caller