# EOS transactions for Future execution

Tags: cleos, nodeos, keosd

There is slight confusion about creating and signing transaction which I can process/send in future date.

My understanding is that to create a transaction, it must have following attributes values entered:

```
"expiration": "2018-12-17T16:40:51",  <<<===== after this time the transaction can never be included in a block 
"ref_block_num": 427225,              <<<===== take this value from Get Blockchain Info response
"ref_block_prefix": 821895182,
```

1. Do I have to have latest block information to create a transaction?
2. Can I create a transaction which can be executed in future let say after a day or so? Currently my transactions expires in 1 minutes on my local node.

Answer (score 1):

Ans 1: Yes, you have to add this information as it helps in validating and adding the blocks in the blockchain.

Ans 2: Yes, EOS has this concept of deferred transaction which lets you execute your transaction after a certain delay. To create a deferred transaction, check out this question.

[How can I create a deferred transaction?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-can-i-create-a-deferred-transaction)

Comment: As I understand deferred tx can only be created by smart contracts? If i need to create a deferred tx manually, can i do it?

Comment: As per my knoweledge, i don't think that can be done by command line. You have to write an action inside you smart contract wrapping a transaction with delay.